# How does whitelisting work with a wifi extender?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender, whitelist

I have setup a wifi to whitelist the known MAC addresses of my devices. Now I would like to extend the range with a wifi extender. Do I have to add its MAC address to the list of the router?

And if I change the extended SSID name (from "my_current_network_name" to "my_current_network_name_ex" or something like that, will I inherit the same whitelisting or I could setup a different list ?

Comment: I have searched but it seems to me that the specific issue of whitelisting was not asked on the site, please point me to eventual duplicates!

Answer (score 1):

If your router is using a whitelist you have to add the extender MAC address to it. First of all, a Extender only "extends" the Network and does nothing else. Therefore your Router needs to block certain Devices. Depending of the extender you are able to use Whitelists but I dont see the point. Simply block all unwanted Devices on your router and let the extender be an extender. If your extender supports whitelists you will need to take care of 2 whitelists. One on the router and one on the extender.

Comment: Please tell me how to improve the details. I am referring to a wifi router + a wifi range extender. The wifi router has a whitelist. Do I have to add the MAC address of the wifi range extender to this whitelist? Does the concept of two separate whitelists even make sense or it "doesn't work that way"? if you can tell me what's unclear in my question I'll try to improve it.

Comment: If you want to use Whitelists then yes, you would need to add the Extenders MAC to the routers whitelist. Then also add MACs from all the other devices to router and extender (if supported). However, it does not make much sense to me as it is one more whitelist to take care of. If there are not tons of people trying to flood your extender, then I dont see the point in taking care of 2 whitelists. Simply use the whitelist on the router and leave the extender "open".

Comment: So if my router uses a whitelist (it does) I *have* to add the extender MAC address to it. Could you add this to your answeR?

Comment: Yes and done ;)